# How to select multiple columns from dataset into a string list with LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, multiple-columns

Okay now this below is working

```
     List<string> lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows.
Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r["Column1"].ToString()).ToList();
```

But i want to make it work like below and not working

```
     List<string> lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows.
Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r["Column1"].ToString(),r => r["Column2"].ToString(),r => r["Column3"].ToString()).ToList();
```

So instead of 1 dataset datarow column, i want to add multiple columns into the list.
How can i do that ?

Comment: You'd get a list of string arrays. Is that what you want? Presumably you'd like a list of an object with several string properties, no?

Comment: "not working" is not clear. What do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: Can you give an example with data?

Comment: check @SWeko answer. SelectMany is solving my problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use S[electMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) if you just to dump the contents of the fields into a list.

```
List<string> lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows
 .Cast<DataRow>()
 .SelectMany(r => new string[]{
                    r["Column1"].ToString(),
                    r["Column2"].ToString(),
                    r["Column3"].ToString()})
 .ToList();
```

If however, you want to extract the fields into another object, you could do something like:

```
class KnownMove {
   public string Column1 {get; set;}
   public string Column2 {get; set;}
   public string Column3 {get; set;}
}

List<KnownMove > lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows
 .Cast<DataRow>()
 .SelectMany(r => new KnownMove{
                    Column1 = r["Column1"].ToString(),
                    Column2 = r["Column2"].ToString(),
                    Column3 = r["Column3"].ToString()})
 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you want to be able to access each column individually, you'd want to return an array of strings.

```
 List<string[]> lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows
                          .Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new[] 
                               { 
                                  r["Column1"].ToString(),  
                                  r["Column2"].ToString(), 
                                  r["Column3"].ToString() 
                               }).ToList();
```

Then for each row, you can get the string value of a column by index:

```
 foreach(var item in lstKnownMoves) 
      Console.WriteLine("Column1: {0} Column2: {1} Column3: {2}", item);
```

If you want basically a map of columns, and would rather not create a class to act as a tuple as in the selected answer, you can use `List<dynamic>`:

```
 List<dynamic> lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows
                          .Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new 
                               { 
                                  Column1 = r["Column1"].ToString(),  
                                  Column2 = r["Column2"].ToString(), 
                                  Column3 = r["Column3"].ToString() 
                               }).ToList<dynamic>();

 foreach(var item in lstKnownMoves) 
      Console.WriteLine("Column1: {0} Column2: {1} Column3: {2}", 
          item.Column1, item.Column2, item.Column3);
```

Comment: no i don't want to access each individually. i want to add those 3 columns to the list. thanks.

Comment: This _does_ add the three columns to the list. It's not clear what you are asking. You're asking for a `List<string>`, but unless you just string concat all three columns (which seems to me to be entirely useless), you can't get at each column for each row unless you change the list element from `string` to `string[]` (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a list of an object with several string properties instead of a list of string arrays.

```
List<object> lstKnownMoves = dsAttacksTemp.Tables[0].Rows.
Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new { 
 Col1 = r["Column1"].ToString(), 
 Col2 = r["Column2"].ToString(), 
 Col3 = r["Column3"].ToString()
}).ToList();
```

This way you'd get a `List<T>` where `T` is an anonymous object with 3 string properties, namely `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3`. I guess this is what you are asking for.

Comment: thanks i tried this before asking but not working http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/5091/errorggn.png

Comment: it's not a `List<string>` it's a `List<object>`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: ye but it is not solving my problem. object. check SWeko answer it is working great